# DO app hosting a site attempting to connect to a DO Droplet hosting an API results in an unhandled rejection

Tags: python, react-native, digital-ocean

There are two components to my application:

- A DO 'App' which hosts a react website. This website makes requests to:
- A DO 'Droplet' which hosts an API

When I attempt to connect from my development environment the Droplet, data is returned and the locally deployed react app displays the data.

However, when I deploy the react app onto the DO App and attempt to make the same request, I receive the error: `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Not allowed to request resource`. The browser console provides the following.

```
Not allowed to request resource
Fetch API cannot load http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/search/ due to access control checks
Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: Not allowed to request resource.
```

I have attempted both the public IP for the Droplet hosting the API as well as the private IP. The same issue occurs once the application is deployed on the DO app.

## Error

What areas can I look where there might be an issue?

```
const fetchReferences = async () => {

fetch(’http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/search/’, {. //this is the line that errors. 
method: ‘POST’,
body: JSON.stringify({
url: searchState.searchCriteria
```

On the python API I'm allowing everything through:

```
app = Flask(name)
CORS(app, resources={r"/“: {"origins”: “”}})
api = Api(app)
parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
```

## Logging

**Refgator API output log**
[image]

**Refgator API error log**

[image]

## CORS issues?

So...

**Why does an instance of the website loaded locally with yarn connect successfully to the droplet?**

I suspect that this may be due to having shared keys with the Droplet hosting the API.

**Why does an instance of the website loaded on the DO App platform connect without success to the droplet?**

I have seen posts relating CORS issues between droplets and apps hosted on Digital Ocean. See [here](https://ideas.digitalocean.com/ideas/APPX-I-94) and [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/app-platform-could-there-be-a-allow_headers-option-for-cors).

My knowledge on CORS is non-existent so confirming this is extremely time consuming.

---

It may be best to move the repo back to bitbucket and attempt to use a droplet rather than an app.

Comment: I am not familiar with the DO App platform, so I cannot help solve your problem. But I can tell you that when you see things like `due to access control` (as in the first error your posted) it is typically due to CORS. In the documentation for the DO App platform, there should be examples on how/where to set up the backend API server.

Comment: Also, people at serverfault might be more into this sort of question.

Comment: Thanks @Yogesch, I'll put it on there too. https://serverfault.com/questions/1069794/do-app-hosting-a-site-attempting-to-connect-to-a-do-droplet-hosting-an-api-resul